# Tensorflow difference between working with tf.layers or specifying through tf.get_variable

Tags: tensorflow

My code consists of a general part (not shown) and a variable part (see blocks of code). When the next block is used everything works well:

```
def generator(x, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=reuse):
        # initializers
        w_init = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=0.02)
        b_init = tf.constant_initializer(0.)
        # 1st hidden layer
        w0 = tf.get_variable('G_w0', [x.get_shape()[1], 256], initializer=w_init)
        b0 = tf.get_variable('G_b0', [256], initializer=b_init)
        h0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w0) + b0)
        # 2nd hidden layer
        w1 = tf.get_variable('G_w1', [h0.get_shape()[1], 512], initializer=w_init)
        b1 = tf.get_variable('G_b1', [512], initializer=b_init)
        h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h0, w1) + b1)
        # 3rd hidden layer
        w2 = tf.get_variable('G_w2', [h1.get_shape()[1], 1024], initializer=w_init)
        b2 = tf.get_variable('G_b2', [1024], initializer=b_init)
        h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1, w2) + b2)
        # output hidden layer
        w3 = tf.get_variable('G_w3', [h2.get_shape()[1], 784], initializer=w_init)
        b3 = tf.get_variable('G_b3', [784], initializer=b_init)
        o = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(h2, w3) + b3)
    return o

def discriminator(x, drop_out, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):
        x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 784])
        # initializers
        w_init = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=0.02)
        b_init = tf.constant_initializer(0.)
        # 1st hidden layer
        w0 = tf.get_variable('D_w0', [x.get_shape()[1], 1024], initializer=w_init)
        b0 = tf.get_variable('D_b0', [1024], initializer=b_init)
        h0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w0) + b0)
        h0 = tf.nn.dropout(h0, 1-drop_out)
        # 2nd hidden layer
        w1 = tf.get_variable('D_w1', [h0.get_shape()[1], 512], initializer=w_init)
        b1 = tf.get_variable('D_b1', [512], initializer=b_init)
        h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h0, w1) + b1)
        h1 = tf.nn.dropout(h1, 1-drop_out)
    # 3rd hidden layer
        w2 = tf.get_variable('D_w2', [h1.get_shape()[1], 256], initializer=w_init)
        b2 = tf.get_variable('D_b2', [256], initializer=b_init)
        h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1, w2) + b2)
        h2 = tf.nn.dropout(h2, 1-drop_out)
    # output layer
        w3 = tf.get_variable('D_w3', [h2.get_shape()[1], 1], initializer=w_init)
        b3 = tf.get_variable('D_b3', [1], initializer=b_init)
        o = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h2, w3) + b3)
    return o
```

When the following block is used (which should do exactly the same as the previous block, right?) the training does not work anymore:

```
def generator(x, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=reuse):
        w_init = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
        b_init = tf.constant_initializer(0.)
        l1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 256, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 512, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        l3 = tf.layers.dense(l2, 1024, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        o = tf.layers.dense(l3, 784, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    return o

def discriminator(x, drop_out, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):
        x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 784])
        w_init = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
        b_init = tf.constant_initializer(0.)
        l1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 1024, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        l1_ = tf.layers.dropout(l1, drop_out)
        l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1_, 512, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        l2_ = tf.layers.dropout(l2, drop_out)
        l3 = tf.layers.dense(l2_, 256, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        l3_ = tf.layers.dropout(l3, drop_out)
        o = tf.layers.dense(l3_, 1, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    return o
```

I don't understand where the difference can be, but when learning and looking at the images created there clearly is a difference. The first block works always perfectly. The second one only for a few iterations.

Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I cannot make a comment... The only thing came to my mind is that `tf.nn.dropout` uses `keep_prob` while `tf.layers.dropout` uses dropout rate. Please check if this rate is too high.

Comment: And I just checked if the first part of the first code block (= generator 1) works well with the second part of the second code block (= discriminator 2) and vice versa. Conclusion: generator 2 + discriminator 1 --> okay; generator 1 + discriminator 2 --> NOT okay! So I guess there is something wrong with discriminator 2?

Comment: @JeroenBertels `tf.layers.dropout` has parameter `training=False` by default, which does not use dropout in your case. I wonder if that is the problem. If you are using different `keep_prob` in `tf.nn.dropout` for training and inference properly, discriminator 1 is typically more robust than discriminator 2.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I found out this was the problem indeed. To make the two blocks equivalent (as in that they act identical in the entire script) I had to add 'training=True' to 'tf.layers.dropout'. But, besides that, you say that discriminator 1 is generally more robust. Why is that then?

Comment: @JeroenBertels Sorry for the confusion. I mean, from the classification perspective, since discriminator 1 used dropout while discriminator 2 did not, discriminator 1 was less prone to overfitting the data (thus more robust). From the GAN perspective, discriminator 1 may perform better because it was not too harsh on the generator during early training and did not cause severe mode collapse. It would be interesting to see 1. how dropout rate affects the training of generator; 2. if same performance can be achieved without dropout but other tricks on the generator.